# Draw Perpendicular line between two lines in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to draw a perpendicular line between P1 and P2 corresponding to P3.
I have P1 and P2, when I touch on UIView P3 will make.
Now I want to draw perpendicular line from P3 corresponding to P1 and P2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need a bit of math... In theory you need to draw a line from `P3` to point `X` which lies between `P1` and `P2`. The vector between `P1` and `X` is actually a projection of `P3-P1` to a line described by `P1` and `P2`. So:

```
X = P1 + (P3-P1)*((P2-P1)/(|P2-P1|)) * ((P2-P1)/(|P2-P1|))
```

To use `CGPoint` this could work:

```
func projectedPoint(_ point: CGPoint, toLine line: (a: CGPoint, b: CGPoint)) -> CGPoint {

    guard line.a != line.b else { return .zero } // Not a line

    let direction: CGPoint = {
        // A direction of line with a distance of 1
        let a = line.a
        let b = line.b
        let subtraction = CGPoint(x: b.x - a.x, y: b.y - a.y)
        let distance = sqrt(subtraction.x*subtraction.x + subtraction.y*subtraction.y)
        return CGPoint(x: subtraction.x/distance, y: subtraction.y/distance)
    }()

    let projectionDistance: CGFloat = {
        let vector = CGPoint(x: point.x-line.a.x, y: point.y-line.a.y) // From A to POINT
        return vector.x*direction.x + vector.y*direction.y // A simple dot product
    }()

    return CGPoint(x: line.a.x + direction.x*projectionDistance, y: line.a.y + direction.y*projectionDistance)
}
```

So in your case:

```
X = projectedPoint(P3, toLine:(P1, P2))
```

Now you simply draw a line between `X` and `P3`.

Or if you want it more function based the following should do. It should also be easy to port this to any system operating with 2D vectors which usually already includes all the provided functions:

```
func projectedPoint(_ point: CGPoint, toLine line: (a: CGPoint, b: CGPoint)) -> CGPoint {

    guard line.a != line.b else { return .zero } // Not a line

    func add(_ a: CGPoint, _ b: CGPoint) -> CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: a.x + b.x, y: a.y + b.y) }
    func subtract(_ a: CGPoint, _ b: CGPoint) -> CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: a.x - b.x, y: a.y - b.y) }
    func scale(_ a: CGPoint, _ b: CGFloat) -> CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: a.x*b, y: a.y*b) }
    func dot(_ a: CGPoint, _ b: CGPoint) -> CGFloat { return a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y }
    func length(_ a: CGPoint) -> CGFloat { return sqrt(a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y) }
    func normalize(_ a: CGPoint) -> CGPoint { return scale(a, 1.0/length(a)) }

    let direction: CGPoint = normalize(subtract(line.b, line.a))
    let projectionDistance = dot(subtract(point, line.a), direction)

    return add(line.a, scale(direction, projectionDistance))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometry question I believe. Anyway, given a line which is segmented into P1P2, you want to draw a perpendicular from an external point named P3.

You can find the point in which perpendicular line meets P1P2 as follows:

let coordinates of P1 be (x1,y1), coordinates of P2 be (x2,y2), coordinates of P3 be (x3,y3) and coordinates of (x4,y4) be the point which perpendicular meets the line.

x4 and y4 can be determined by:

```
k = ((y2-y1) * (x3-x1) - (x2-x1) * (y3-y1)) / ((y2-y1)^2 + (x2-x1)^2)
x4 = x3 - k * (y2-y1)
y4 = y3 + k * (x2-x1)
```

Once, x4 and y4 is determined, you can now draw the perpendicular line from P3 to (x4,y4).

This was the geometry; Drawing line using UIKit or getting coordinate of points is another matter.